# Using VBA to copy a (fixed range) iterated column in Sheet1 to a range of columns in Sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of numbers in Sheet1 (AG6:AG25) that contain the `RAND()` function, and I'm looking to iterate the outcomes for each via pasting transposed values into Sheet2 on a new row for each iteration.

Solved as follows:

```
Sub MonteCarlo()

Dim transposedVariant As Variant
Dim sourceRowRange As Range
Dim sourceRowRangeVariant As Variant
Dim rangeFilledWithTransposedData As Range
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 1 To 5000

    Set sourceRowRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AG6:AG25")
    sourceRowRangeVariant = sourceRowRange.Value
    transposedVariant = Application.Transpose(sourceRowRangeVariant)

    Set rangeFilledWithTransposedData = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i & ":T" & i)
    rangeFilledWithTransposedData.Value = transposedVariant

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try  as step 3? Please show your code. If we don't see what you did we cannot tell what you did wrong and how to correct it. • Note there are approximately 100 questions about how to find the last used row/column here on the Stack.

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: Hello both, sorry for not giving an example as it was failing to compile. I've reached a solution that is complete, aside from one syntax I can't figure out. Please see updated :)

Comment: @Chris Where do you get errors and which? And you cannot transpose a value `Application.Transpose(sourceRowRangeVariant)` instead transpose the range `Application.Transpose(sourceRowRange)`

Answer (score -1):

Please find the code. I hope it will help you.

Sub simulation()

Dim i As Long

Dim j As Long

For i = 1 To 1000

```
For j = 1 To 20

'Calculate


    Sheet1.Cells(j, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(100, 150) * 1


Next j
```

Next i

End Sub

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question? He is already performing a Rand function, he wants to know how to copy the range in sheet1 and paste into the first empty column in Sheet2, after each Rand recalculation. Your code only puts random numbers into Sheet1, Range (A1:A20) again and again.